# Remove nested column in PySpark

Tags: python, apache-spark, pyspark, apache-spark-sql, schema

I have a PySpark dataframe with a column results. Inside the results column I want to remove the column "Attributes".

The schema of the dataframe (there are more columns, but I have not shown them for convenience because the schema is large):

```
 |-- results: struct (nullable = true)
 |    |-- l: array (nullable = true)
 |    |    |-- element: struct (containsNull = true)
 |    |    |    |-- m: struct (nullable = true)
 |    |    |    |    |-- Attributes: struct (nullable = true)
 |    |    |    |    |    |-- m: struct (nullable = true)
 |    |    |    |    |    |    |-- Score: struct (nullable = true)
 |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |-- n: string (nullable = true)
 |    |    |    |    |-- OtherInfo: struct (nullable = true)
 |    |    |    |    |    |-- l: array (nullable = true)
 |    |    |    |    |    |    |-- element: struct (containsNull = true)
 |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |-- m: struct (nullable = true)
 |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |-- Name: string (nullable = true)
```

How to do this without a udf in PySpark?

One row of data:

```
{
   "results" : {
        "l" : [
            {
              "m":{
                  "Attributes" : {
                      "m" : {
                           "Score" : {"n" : "85"}
                       }
                  },
                   "OtherInfo":{
                      "l" : [
                           {
                             "m" : {
                               "Name" : {"john"}
                             }
                          },
                          {
                             "m" : {
                                "Name" : "Cena"}
                          }
                       ]
                   }
             }
           }   
         ]
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To delete a field from a struct type you have to create a new struct with all the elements but the one you want to delete from the original struct.

Here, as the field `l` under `results` is an array, you could use [`transform`](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/sql/index.html#transform) function (Spark 2.4+) to update all its struct elements like this:

```
from pyspark.sql.functions import struct, expr


t_expr = "transform(results.l, x -> struct(struct(x.m.OtherInfo as OtherInfo) as m))"
df = df.withColumn("results", struct(expr(t_expr).alias("l")))
```

For each element `x` in the array, we create new struct that holds only `x.m.OtherInfo` field.

```
df.printSchema()

#root
# |-- results: struct (nullable = false)
# |    |-- l: array (nullable = true)
# |    |    |-- element: struct (containsNull = false)
# |    |    |    |-- m: struct (nullable = false)
# |    |    |    |    |-- OtherInfo: struct (nullable = true)
# |    |    |    |    |    |-- l: array (nullable = true)
# |    |    |    |    |    |    |-- element: struct (containsNull = true)
# |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |-- m: struct (nullable = true)
# |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |-- Name: string (nullable = true)
```

Comment: nice solution! If there is say one more field otherinfo2 how to pass it in transform

Comment: Just add it to the new struct : `struct(x.m.OtherInfo as OtherInfo, x.m.OtherInfo2 as OtherInfo2)`. If you have many fields and you don't want to hardcode them, you can get the filed names from the schema and build the transform expression string using Python loop.

Comment: cool. If say now for some item there was no otherinfo(it is null in some case or does not exist) then would this work. and how would otherinfo be populated then in the transformed frame?

Comment: @kmkhan Yes it should work too. Those fileds will be then null.

Comment: ParseException: "\nmismatched input 'as' expecting {')', ','}(line 1, pos 70)\n\n== SQL ==\ntransform(results.l, x -> f.struct(f.struct(x.m.OtherInfo as OtherInfo) as m))     I got this exception.

Answer (score 4):

Since **Spark 3.1**, [**`dropFields`**](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/python/reference/pyspark.sql/api/pyspark.sql.Column.dropFields.html#pyspark.sql.Column.dropFields) can be used without recreating the rest of a large schema.

```py
df = df.withColumn(
    "results",
    F.struct(F.transform(
        F.col("results.l"),
        lambda x: x.m.dropFields("Attributes")
    )).alias("l")
)
```

Result:

```py
df.printSchema()
# root
#  |-- results: struct (nullable = false)
#  |    |-- l: array (nullable = false)
#  |    |    |-- element: struct (containsNull = false)
#  |    |    |    |-- OtherInfo: struct (nullable = false)
#  |    |    |    |    |-- l: array (nullable = false)
#  |    |    |    |    |    |-- element: struct (containsNull = false)
#  |    |    |    |    |    |    |-- m: struct (nullable = false)
#  |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |-- Name: string (nullable = true)
```