# Pyspark modify values of JSON fields without changing schema

Tags: python, json, pyspark, apache-spark-sql

I need to modify values of nested JSON using pyspark and keep the schema intact, schema should be same as the original JSON, only values needs to be modified for few fields.

Below is my sample json:

I want to modify values of below fields:

- TAG1, TAG2
- Account fields -ADDR1 & ADDR2
- Holder fields -ADDR1 & ADDR2

SOURCE JSON:

```
{
  "references": [
    {
      "TAG1": VALUE1,
      "TAG2": "VALUE2",
      "TAG3": VALUE3,
      "TAG4": "VALUE4",
      "account": [
        {
          "ID": A_VALUE1,
          "BANK_ID": A_VALUE2,
          "ADDR1": "A_VALUE3",
          "ADDR2": "A_VALUE4"
        }
      ],
      "holder": {
           "ID": H_VALUE1,
          "BANK_ID": H_VALUE2,
          "ADDR1": "H_VALUE3",
          "ADDR2": "H_VALUE4"
      }
    },
    {
      "TAG1": VALUE1,
      "TAG2": "VALUE2",
      "TAG3": VALUE3,
      "TAG4": "VALUE4",
      "account": [
        {
          "ID": A_VALUE1,
          "BANK_ID": A_VALUE2,
          "ADDR1": "A_VALUE3",
          "ADDR2": "A_VALUE4"
        }
      ],
      "holder": {
           "ID": H_VALUE1,
          "BANK_ID": H_VALUE2,
          "ADDR1": "H_VALUE3",
          "ADDR2": "H_VALUE4"
      }
    }
    ]
}
```

OUTPUT JSON:

```
{
  "references": [
    {
      "TAG1": NEW_VALUE1,
      "TAG2": "NEW_VALUE2",
      "TAG3": VALUE3,
      "TAG4": "VALUE4",
      "account": [
        {
          "ID": A_VALUE1,
          "BANK_ID": A_VALUE2,
          "ADDR1": "NEW_ADDR1",
          "ADDR2": "NEW_ADDR2"
        }
      ],
      "holder": {
           "ID": H_VALUE1,
          "BANK_ID": H_VALUE2,
          "ADDR1": "NEW_ADDR1",
          "ADDR2": "NEW_ADDR2"
      }
    },
    {
      "TAG1": NEW_VALUE1,
      "TAG2": "NEW_VALUE2",
      "TAG3": VALUE3,
      "TAG4": "VALUE4",
      "account": [
        {
          "ID": A_VALUE1,
          "BANK_ID": A_VALUE2,
          "ADDR1": "NEW_ADDR1",
          "ADDR2": "NEW_ADDR2"
        }
      ],
      "holder": {
           "ID": H_VALUE1,
          "BANK_ID": H_VALUE2,
          "ADDR1": "NEW_ADDR1",
          "ADDR2": "NEW_ADDR2"
      }
    }
    ]
}
```

Comment: Have you tried any code? See [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65913892/update-the-nested-json-with-another-nested-json-using-python/65953629#65953629) as a starting point.

Comment: @mck yes I tried few approaches , the question link you shared is not helpful as I need to modify the same json.

Comment: You should show your attempts in the question.

Comment: @mck, I tried quite a few options like I am able to update the JSON using UDF , but the data frame is storing it as string and I'm not able to convert it to JSON back. I do not wanted to cluster the post , wanted to keep clear and concise.

Comment: You can use `transform` function to update each struct in the array column. You can see an example here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/62385071/1386551. Using some python code you can generate the transfrom expression from the json fields.

Comment: @blackbishop Thanks I m going thru the article , I says about deletion of fields , if possible can u please share an example of modifying field value using transform, I am new to pyspark.

Comment: @blackbishop Sorry I have updated the post I need to modify the values for those fields, I need to mask them with ******** string

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `transform` function to update the struct elements of `references` array column :

```
from pyspark.sql import functions as F

transform_expr = """
transform(references, x -> struct(
                                'NEW_VALUE1' as TAG1, 
                                'NEW_VALUE2' as TAG2,
                                x.TAG3 as TAG3,
                                x.TAG4 as TAG4,
                                transform(x.account, i -> struct(
                                                             i.ID as ID,
                                                             i.BANK_ID as BANK_ID,
                                                             'NEW_ADDR1' as ADDR1,
                                                             'NEW_ADDR2' as ADDR2
                                                         )
                                ) as account,
                                struct(
                                   x.holder.ID AS ID,
                                   x.holder.BANK_ID AS BANK_ID,
                                   'NEW_ADDR1' AS ADDR1,
                                   'NEW_ADDR2' AS ADDR2
                                ) as holder 
                            )
)                            
"""

df1 = df.withColumn("references", F.expr(transform_expr))

print(df1.toJSON().first())
# {"references":[{"TAG1":"NEW_VALUE1","TAG2":"NEW_VALUE2","TAG3":"VALUE3","TAG4":"VALUE4","account":[{"ID":"A_VALUE1","BANK_ID":"A_VALUE2","ADDR1":"NEW_ADDR1","ADDR2":"NEW_ADDR2"}],"holder":{"ID":"H_VALUE1","BANK_ID":"H_VALUE2","ADDR1":"NEW_ADDR1","ADDR2":"NEW_ADDR2"}},{"TAG1":"NEW_VALUE1","TAG2":"NEW_VALUE2","TAG3":"VALUE3","TAG4":"VALUE4","account":[{"ID":"A_VALUE1","BANK_ID":"A_VALUE2","ADDR1":"NEW_ADDR1","ADDR2":"NEW_ADDR2"}],"holder":{"ID":"H_VALUE1","BANK_ID":"H_VALUE2","ADDR1":"NEW_ADDR1","ADDR2":"NEW_ADDR2"}}]}


df1.write.json("...") # write output json
```

Comment: Thanks for the response, cant we keep only those fields for those values to be modified ? because there might be a case where every json will not have all the fields mentioned in the transform expression. There are cases where there will be no holder tag as well.

Comment: @nilesh1212 No, when updating a struct type you can't ignore other fields. To handle the changing schema you can read all JSON files at once, this way the schemas will be merged so no worry about missing fields in some files. You can also pass the schema when reading the json `df.read.json(path, schema)`. Missing fields will have null values (but are not written back with `df.write.json`)

Comment: Thanks I am able to get the desired output, but one more question is this the only solution to achieve this,  in order to get this working I have created a python function which generates the transformation expression ,I feel the solution is lengthy, do we have  better alternate solution for this issue, like just editing the required field and store it as json.

Comment: @nilesh1212 Another option is to explode all the nested arrays, update the fields you want, and then groupBy and collect lists to get back the original schema, so not sure if it's more optimal than using `transform` on array.